# How can i read text inside a xml tag element in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

i am able to read text between the tags using java, but i also need to read  value which inside the tag.

```
<Events>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"><System><Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService" Guid="{747ef6fd-e535-4d16-b510-42c90f6873a1}"></Provider>
<EventID Qualifiers="">800</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>43</Task>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x4004000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-11-17 09:25:22.909933"></TimeCreated>
<EventRecordID>1</EventRecordID>
<Correlation ActivityID="" RelatedActivityID=""></Correlation>
<Execution ProcessID="1428" ThreadID="8052"></Execution>
<Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational</Channel>
<Computer>DESKTOP-0QUNS51</Computer>
<Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3467767592-1575844298-3693013382-1002"></Security>
</System>
<UserData><JobDiag xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2005/08/windows/printing/spooler/core/events"><JobId>8</JobId>
</JobDiag>
</UserData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Post your code and the xml.

Comment: <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-11-17 09:25:22.909933"></TimeCreated>, need to get SystemTime value

Comment: @Rahul - please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Comment: You should use DOM  or SAX Parser to traverse xml files

Comment: posted the sample xml wherein ineed to get SystemTime value